# Ballerina Java Cast Exception

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-java-interop

I'm running the code form the java support [learning page](https://ballerina.io/learn/calling-java-code-from-ballerina/#support-for-java-casting) and get an exception when I try to build it. Here are the steps I did:

1. Generate bindings:

```
ballerina bindgen -o src/test java.io.FileInputStream java.io.InputStream --public
```

2. Copy sample code

```
import ballerina/java;

type FileInputStreamTypedesc typedesc<FileInputStream>;
function test(){
    InputStream inputStream = check newFileInputStream3("sample.txt");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = <FileInputStream>check java:cast(inputStream, FileInputStreamTypedesc);
}
```

3. build

```
ballerina build test

Compiling source
        acme/test:0.0.1
error: acme/test:0.0.1::main.bal:7:85: incompatible types: expected 'typedesc<ballerina/java:JObject>', found 'typedesc<typedesc<acme/test:0.0.1:FileInputStream>>'
```

used versions:

- jBallerina 1.2.13
- Language specification 2020R1
- Update Tool 0.8.10

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [learn](https://ballerina.io/learn/calling-java-code-from-ballerina/#support-for-java-casting) page you mentioned is for the Ballerina Swan Lake release. But it seems, anyway, for the [1.2.x version](https://ballerina.io/1.2/learn/calling-java-code-from-ballerina/#support-for-java-casting) learn page also the same content is there and it is incorrect.

For the moment, you can update Ballerina to the Swan Lake version (which is anyway the latest); the way to do this is mentioned [here](https://ballerina.io/downloads/). Afterward, you would be able to execute the mentioned code successfully.

Cheers,
Anjana.